# Slowmotion except main player?

Tags: unity

My script works fine except I don't know how to not let the slow-motion affect the main player.

```
public GameObject player;

void  Update () {
    if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.A)) {
        Time.timeScale = 0.5;
        Time.fixedDeltaTime = 0.02F * Time.timeScale;
    }

    if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Z)) {
        Time.timeScale = 1.0f;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Not so experienced with Unity, but i'm pretty sure you can revert that `timeScale` effect by multiplying the `deltaTime` with the `timeScale` whenever you need it. For example:

```
// In a player movement update function
transform.Translate(Vector3.forward * Time.deltaTime / Time.timeScale);
```

Comment: Generally you'll want to read from `Time.deltaTime` rather than `fixedDeltaTime`. If you access `deltaTime` in `FixedUpdate`/`WaitForFixedUpdate` it will give you the fixed timestep automatically, and the frame timestep everywhere else. That way it's less prone to timing errors if you call a helper method from both fixed and frame update loops, or if you move code between fixed & frame.

Comment: @DMGregory Fixed it.

Answer (score 1):

You could slow down everything and speed up the player instead. If your game is multiplayer and you need to use this feature there, I suggest that you tie your calculations into `Time.deltaTime` along with a `float scale` variable so that you can "speed up" or "slow down" anything that you need to.

For example (untested code, but the logic should work if you try different stuff):

```
Time.timeScale = 0.5f; //change this to scale your game speed
playerActionScale = 2f; //change this to account for player action speed

if(Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Left))
{
 player.transform.Rotate(angle * Time.deltaTime * playerActionScale);
}
```

If you're planning on using this sort of time scaling too much, I really do recommend designing your game logic around that feature.

Comment: You probably want to multiply by Time.deltaTime rather than Time.timeScale. That way variability in framerate is also accounted for correctly.